# What board game is this piece from?

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-game-piece

These little blue pieces came in baggies of 12, all identical (same color and shape). These are metal, but there were also little baggies of plastic pieces - same size and color. They are approx 1" tall, 1" wide, and 1/4" thick. There are no markings on them. What game did they come from? What are they used for? Thanks!

[image: They are 1" tall, 1" wide, and 1/4" thick.]

Comment: Do you actually know they are board game pieces?

Comment: Yes, they were on a table with only board game pieces at a board game convention.

Comment: Metal board game pieces are practically unheard of. The only pieces I've seen made of metal were coins in fancy versions.